# GL version 2.1 with the gpu_shader4 extension is not supported by your graphics driver

Tags: linux, opengl, paraview

I have downloaded ParaView for Linux(from their web site).I try to run the code but

```
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x37418c0): GL version 2.1 with the gpu_shader4 extension is not supported by your graphics driver but is required for the new OpenGL rendering backend. Please update your OpenGL driver. If you are using Mesa please make sure you have version 10.6.5 or later and make sure your driver in Mesa supports OpenGL 3.2.
```

My gl info

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.0.0-rc1
milenko@milenko-HP-Compaq-6830s:~/ParaView-5.0.1/bin$ glxinfo | grep 'version'
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.0.0-rc1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30

glxinfo | egrep 'OpenGL|glx'
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV620 (DRM 2.40.0, LLVM 3.4.0)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.0.0-rc1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
```

With lspci | grep -i vga

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV620/M82 [Mobility Radeon HD 3410/3430]
```

My X driver

```
glxinfo | grep -i vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
```

Mesa is not outdated,I do not understand what should I do. I am on Ubuntu 14.04,64bit.

Comment: »» not supported by your graphics driver «« : The most important information is missing in your post : The graphics → e.g. $ `lspci | grep -i "vga compatible"` .... and the driver in use. Please edit your post to include those specifications. -

Comment: @KnudLarsen Take a look at my edit please.

Comment: The error message doesn't say that it requires just OpenGL 2.1. It requires OpenGL 2.1 and **additionally**  the `GL_EXT_gpu_shader4` extension which you'll generally find only on GL 3.x capable hardware. `glxinfo` will list all of the available extensions, so you can `grep` for it.

Comment: @derhass Thanks,then it means I can not use it my laptop?Grahics card is not good enough?

Comment: As the error message explicitely puts it: "and make sure your driver in Mesa supports OpenGL 3.2".

Comment: @derhass Can you tell me terminal input, glxinfo ..?

Comment: `glxinfo | grep GL_EXT_gpu_shader4` will either return nothing, meaning it's not supported, or it will print a line with the string somewhere inside, meaning it should be supported.

Comment: @derhass Returns nothing!

Comment: galium 0.4 on rv620 support up to gl3.3 (but gpu_shader4 is not complete) Compile latest mesa from their git repos (at least last stable version) make sure --enable-texture-float is on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your GL implementation is insufficient for the new requirements for ParaView with version 5.0. Linux binaries from paraview.org are bundled with a approriate Mesa 3D build with required extension. Try running paraview as follows to use that Mesa:

```
paraview --mesa-llvm
```

See [this blog](https://blog.kitware.com/messing-with-mesa-for-paraview-5-0vtk-7-0/) for details.